# Correct using of dispatchEvent within Aurelia application

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I've got the following custom element:

```
<template>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon left">${groupAddonLeftText}</div>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control big left-addon right-addon" id="address" value.bind="value & debounce">

    <div class="input-group-addon right">
        <span class="icon ${iconClass}"></span>
    </div>


    <div class="auto-complete-wrapper ${showSuggestions ? 'open': ' '}">
        <ul>
            <li repeat.for="suggestion of suggestions">
                <div click.delegate="selectSuggestion(suggestion)">
                    <p>
                        <strong>${suggestion.street}</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p>${suggestion.city}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

And the viewModel with the `selectSuggestion` method:

```
export class Autocomplete {

    ///removed init stuff for readability

     selectSuggestion(suggestion) {
        this.value = `${suggestion.street}, ${suggestion.city}`;
        this.suggestions = [];
        this.hideSuggestions = true;

        this._dispatchSelectEvent();
    }

    _dispatchSelectEvent() {
        let selectEvent;

        if (window.CustomEvent) {
            selectEvent = new CustomEvent("selected", { bubbles: true });
        } 
        else {
            selectEvent = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
            selectEvent.initCustomEvent("selected", true, true, {});
        }
        this.element.dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
    }

    _createCallbackEvents() {
        $("span.icon-close-cross").on("click", (ev) => {
            let clickEvent;

            if (window.CustomEvent) {
                clickEvent = new CustomEvent("remove", { bubbles: true });
            } else {
                clickEvent = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
                clickEvent.initCustomEvent("remove", true, true, {});
            }
            this.element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm applying the custom element in my html:

```
<autocomplete remove.delegate="remove()" selected.delegate="calculatePrice()"></autocomplete>
```

The `remove` event is dispatched and works perfectly. The `selected` event however is not working, no error no nothing.

What is it that I'm doing wrong? The `remove` event is inspired on this [blogpost](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/08/aurelia-custom-elements-custom-callback-events-tutorial/) and based on this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) I created the `_disptachSelectEvent` method.

See also this gist: https://gist.run/?id=21bc5ce19d2e09a41819b6a930939f96

Comment: Could you provide a gist that reproduces your problem? You can use this gist as a base https://gist.run/?id=5a9c5cda449bfe3789a58122372a0a20. I have some ideas but I have to test them

Comment: @FabioLuz tnx! See my update

Comment: With a tiny tweak (add `this.` in the `calculatePrice()` function), your gist runs fine: https://gist.run/?id=4e214dec2a81e47b45904d745bf5a4ee

Comment: yeah, it's working for me. @AshleyGrant I think you can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Tnx @AshleyGrant although it is enough to get my Gist working this code does not run in my application. I've updated my gist to be exact like my application; still working in gist but not the application.

Comment: Are you possibly on an old version of the framework?

Comment: aurelia-framework@1.0.0-rc.1.0.1; But I found my problem in setting the wrong element :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a tiny tweak (add `this.` in the `calculatePrice()` function), your gist runs fine: https://gist.run/?id=4e214dec2a81e47b45904d745bf5a4ee

```
export class App {
  message = 'Hello World!';

  calculatePrice(){
    this.message = "calculatedPrice!"
  }
}
```